# Apps Script Google Drive CSV Import

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to use a script to import a csv from drive.
Every solution i have found works fine if there is only a "," as seperator.

In my case, i have two seperators, and i can not replace the text seperator.
It looks like there is a problem with importing the text seperator.
How to fix this?

```
id;name;colorGroup;isOnline;publishedAt;material;washing;care;description;additionalDescriptions;offlineOnly;createdAt;updatedAt;modifiedFromCalaogueAt;imageMtime;manufacturerProductId;marketingColor;stock;stockTotal
101000000021;"501 Original Fit Jeans";dunkelblau;1;"2014-05-06 10:27";"100% Baumwolle ";;"Maschinenwäsche bei 30 Grad,Nicht bleichen,Trockenreinigung Kein Trichlorethylen,Trockner bei normaler Temperatur,Heiß bügeln";;"Reguläre Passform mit gerader Beinöffnung,Normale Leibhöhe,Hoher Tragekomfort durch Stretch-Denim,Abriebstellen an den Taschen- und Abschlusskanten,Mit einer Knopfleiste zu verschließen,Bei einer Größe von 1.87 m trägt unser Model Gr. 31/32";;"2015-07-07 11:21";"2021-08-05 14:23";"2021-08-05 02:50";"2015-11-16 11:49";0050101;01;"29/30->0, 29/32->0, 29/34->0, 30/30->3, 30/32->1, 30/34->1, 31/30->1, 31/32->1, 31/34->1, 32/30->0, 32/32->1, 32/34->2, 33/30->1, 33/32->2, 33/34->2, 34/30->0, 34/32->1, 34/34->2";19
```

This is the script.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("productsAll.csv").next();
  var csvString = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
  csvString = csvString.replace(/;/g, ",")
  csvString = csvString.replace(/"/g, "")
  //Logger.log(csvString);
  //csvString = csvString.replace(/\|/g, ".")
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Best regards
Andi

Answer (score 2):

[parseCsv(csv, delimiter)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter)

```js
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("productsAll.csv").next();
  var csvString = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString, ';');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

Comment: Sorry for that - that was just to try if i can handle it without text seperator.

But if i try to import the file with the text seperator it does not work.
Exception: Could not parse text.

Comment: Updated. Is it what you are looking for? I cannot understand well your question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is not an universal solution but for this case I'd consider to make my own CSV parser (it's just one line actually):

```
function make_table() {
  var str = `id;name;colorGroup;isOnline;publishedAt;material;washing;care;description;additionalDescriptions;offlineOnly;createdAt;updatedAt;modifiedFromCalaogueAt;imageMtime;manufacturerProductId;marketingColor;stock;stockTotal
101000000021;"501 Original Fit Jeans";dunkelblau;1;"2014-05-06 10:27";"100% Baumwolle ";;"Maschinenwäsche bei 30 Grad,Nicht bleichen,Trockenreinigung Kein Trichlorethylen,Trockner bei normaler Temperatur,Heiß bügeln";;"Reguläre Passform mit gerader Beinöffnung,Normale Leibhöhe,Hoher Tragekomfort durch Stretch-Denim,Abriebstellen an den Taschen- und Abschlusskanten,Mit einer Knopfleiste zu verschließen,Bei einer Größe von 1.87 m trägt unser Model Gr. 31/32";;"2015-07-07 11:21";"2021-08-05 14:23";"2021-08-05 02:50";"2015-11-16 11:49";0050101;01;"29/30->0, 29/32->0, 29/34->0, 30/30->3, 30/32->1, 30/34->1, 31/30->1, 31/32->1, 31/34->1, 32/30->0, 32/32->1, 32/34->2, 33/30->1, 33/32->2, 33/34->2, 34/30->0, 34/32->1, 34/34->2";19`

  var csvData = str.split('\n').map(x => x.split(';').map(y => y.replace(/"(.+?)"/, '$1')));

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');

  sheet.getRange(1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Output:

[image]

But I don't see how your output should look like. As far as I can tell your CSV has one separator `;`

The column `R` looks wierd. I don't know if it's correct result or you meant to divide it by commas?

[image]

**Update**

You can replace `\n` inside cells with any symbol before you parse the string this way:

```
// replace '\n' inside quotes with symbol
var symbol = '¶';
var m = str.match(/"[^";]*?\n[^"]*?"/g);
if (m) m.forEach(t=>str=str.split(t).join(t.replace(/\n/g,symbol)));
```

It will be look like this in the table:

[image]

The `symbol` can be anything except `\n` or `;` or `,`.

You can replace the `symbol` back to `\n` or `,` or anything after the data will be placed on the sheet. I'd prefer to do it this way:

```
var another_symbol = '\n'
sheet.getDataRange().createTextFinder(symbol).replaceAllWith(another_symbol);
```

But actually it's better to avoid `\n` inside cells.

Comment: Hi Yuri.

Thanks, but the csv has over 50000 lines, so the script is running in a time out. :(

Comment: Sad day. Nevertheless I just found a bug in my RegExp (`str.match...`) and fixed it. Just in case. Amount of the data it's another matter. Probably you need to find the way to grab the data partially.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yuri.

That looks quite perfect.
The only problem i have is, that sometimes there is a new line inside a column as well.
Do you have an idea how to handle this?

For example these three lines:

```
101000009852;Luke;dunkelblau;1;;"99% Baumwolle 1% Elasthan";"Stone washed";"Maschinenwäsche bei 30 Grad,Nicht bleichen,Trockenreinigung Kein Trichlorethylen,Trockner bei reduzierter Temperatur,Nicht heiß bügeln";;"Mittlere Leibhöhe,Knopfverschluss,Reißverschluss,Aufgesetzte Taschen,Metallknöpfe,Farbige Naht,Lederpatches,Ziernaht-Gesäßtaschen";;"1970-01-01 01:33";"2021-08-05 14:23";"2021-08-05 12:53";"2015-11-16 12:07";L719;DXYX;"27/32->0, 28/32->0, 29/32->0, 30/30->0, 30/32->0, 30/34->0, 31/30->0, 31/32->0, 31/34->0, 32/30->0, 32/32->0, 32/34->0, 32/36->0, 33/30->0, 33/32->0, 33/34->0, 33/36->0, 34/30->0, 34/32->0, 34/34->0, 34/36->0, 36/32->0, 36/34->0";0
107000012934;Longsleeve;rot;;"2015-01-14 10:46";"100% Baumwolle ";;"Keine Chemische Reinigung,Maschinenwäsche bei 30 Grad,Nicht bleichen,Nicht in den Trockner,Mäßig heiß bügeln";;"Longsleeve mit seitlichen Schlitzen am Saum,Leicht Verlängerte Rückenpartie";;"1970-01-01 01:33";"2021-08-05 14:23";"2021-08-05 03:13";"2015-11-16 12:13";VICTIM;DustyRed;"L->0, M->0, S->0, XL->0";0
113000003095;Sneaker;beige;1;"2017-10-13 03:05";;;;Größentabelle:;"Kombination aus Mesh und Wildleder,Gummisohle
;;"2015-07-07 11:57";"2021-08-05 14:23";"2021-08-05 03:07";"2015-11-16 12:18";CM1600GR;GreyGreen;11,5->0;0
```

As you can see in the last line after "Gummisohle"